# Varnish Cache and Apache with SSL in Multi Store Envronment

Tags: magento2, varnish

I want to install and configure varnish with Magento 2 on my server running apache as incredibly impressed with the  performance gains. Just wanted to know a bit about configuring SSL with this as have not done this in my dev environment.

I have also however been told by my hosting provider that to have varnish work on my site i can only have one site on my server. Is this correct? My testing shows multiple sites seemingly working fine so wondering what this could be about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varnish in the open source version does not support SSL termination. Therefore you have to set up a reverse proxy like a nginx or similar. The nginx is responsible to terminate the SSL and forward the request to varnish.

Magento 2 works well with varnish, even in a multi-site environment.

As you use Apache, you need to enable mod_proxy. In addition to that add a virtual host that listens to port 443 like so:

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site.com-ssl
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.your-site.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/ 
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.chain
</VirtualHost>
```

The ProxyPass should point to your varnish instance.

Comment: I may swap over to NGINX but am using Apache at the moment and want some advice on SSL termination with Apache really, any thoughts?.

Comment: see answer update

Comment: Brilliant i shall give this a go and have a little test.

Comment: I did seem to get that working but speeds do seem to drop for request by like 1ms to 500ms. Anything to do for this?

Comment: Sorry, I only know some basics of Apache. I never encountered those issues with nginx. You might give it a shot.

Comment: RIght yeah atleast i know speed can be better ill just look into it. Thanks for your help anyway much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about your hosting's comment. Varnish is transparent HTTP caching proxy, it doesn't care how many website go through it. One or one hundred will work equally **fine**.

Worry about your hosting support being incompetent.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check here how to setup varnish cache in magento2

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-varnish-setup/
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html